# How to make routing in asp.net mvc domainname/username so each user has his "username" like facebook does

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to make routing in asp.net mvc domainname/username so each user has his "username" like facebook does

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All answers below don't work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just use the username part as the {id} element, and have a default {action}.

Comment: But in this case I will have to use special routing for all pages which I have in application.

Comment: I don't understand how the system will know is it page or profile and flexible do it

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "UserController", // Route name
            "User/{username}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "UserService", action = "UserInfo" }
```

in the UserController make an action that takes a username as argument:

```
public ActionResult UserInfo(string username)
{
    ///... do your magic here
}
```

Please note that I did not compile this and hence didn't test it :-)

Comment: Sergey means [domain]/[username].

Comment: In that case you just remove part of the path like this: "/{username}" but then you have to handle all the routing magic yourself

Comment: I don't understand how the system will know is it page or profile and flexible do it

Answer (score 2):

Try  This

```
      routes.MapRoute(
           "users", // Route name
           "{username}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "User" } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

and this will be first MapRoute, and action would be like

```
    public ActionResult User(string username)
    {
        return View();
    }
```